# strange behaviour with %in% operator in R

Tags: r

I got this output in R, which I can't understand: I'm looking at whether the entries of the vector `aa` are present in the vector `bb` below. Could anybody explain me why is this that the entries of my output vector aren't all `TRUE`, as one would expect?

```
aa <- seq(0.1, 0.5, by = 0.1)
bb <- seq(0.01, 0.99, by = 0.01)
aa %in% bb
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Thank you

Comment: [10 problems, 1 solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: Ok I see.... Thanks for your quick reply! Well, then I guess the only way out is to loop over my two vectors using `all.equal` (?) This is a bit heavy...

Comment: You don't need to loop, you could do something like this in one line: `sapply(seq_along(aa),function(x){any(abs(aa[x]-bb)<.Machine$double.eps^0.5)})`

Comment: or just do something like `round(aa,2) %in% round(bb,2)` :)

Answer (score -1):

I would convert the vectors into a dataframe initiatlly, as it's easier to work with them as such.

```
library(dplyr)
aa <- seq(0.1, 0.5, by = 0.1)
bb <- seq(0.01, 0.99, by = 0.01)

aa <- as.data.frame(aa)
bb <- as.data.frame(bb)

aa <- mutate(aa, indicator =
        ifelse(aa %in% bb[, "bb"], 1, 0))
```

Comment: This answer does not address the root of the problem: numerical precision. In addition, the suggestion that data.frames are easier to work with than raw vectors is at best a matter of taste. I personally prefer working with vectors in such situations.